# MacVim tabwidth inconsistency issue

Tags: macvim

I have a python script with 3-spaces before each line as indent. Now I want to make further editing easier and added "set tabwidth=3" in my $HOME/.vimrc file. It works when editing under MacVim, however, when later running it, python complained about the inconsistent indent between the original '3-spaces' indents and my new '1-tab' indent. Not sure why and how to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
set ts=3
set expandtab
```

this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Can I have some description about the story behind it?

Comment: With bi/vim i use tabstops instead of tabwidth. The expandtab prevents vim from "compressing" the file at saving by using tabs for every three spaces. This is what messed up your python code. With c/c++ it hardly matters, but with python it does.